# How do I add an alert for when something has been added to a specific folder in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and would like an alert to go off when something has been added to the `data_errors` folder only.

I have already done some research and noticed I can add an event for an S3 bucket for `POST` command but it doesn't really tell me how to specify a specific folder.

Is there a way? Sorry, it's not clear from the docs.

Comment: Which specific docs are you referring to that are not clear? In other words, what programming language are you using to code this? Please share specific code that isn't working for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "would like an alert to go off"? How would you like to be alerted? For example, via email, or do you want a program to be notified?

Comment: I was looking at this doc. The subscription is tied to a PagerDuty Cloudwatch integration URL. 

I was looking at this doc btw: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html

Comment: I was able to get the alarm to trigger via a Cloudwatch alarm. Why not for S3 events?

Comment: The docs clearly explain how to configure S3 events with a prefix. Maybe your problem is getting it into PagerDuty? If so, you likely want the event to trigger an SNS topic that you've subscribed PagerDuty notifications to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can , There is a Prefix option available while adding an event, you need to set it to "data_errors/"

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to get my PagerDuty alarm to trigger though. It's tied to the subscription. I'm certain it works because I was able to trigger an alarm via Cloudwatch tried to the topic. 

I removed the prefix so that all POST events will should trigger a notification but I'm not seeing anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to debug the integration btw cloudwatch and pagerduty

Comment: How do I debug? How would I find the error logs?
I don't know how to debug.

Comment: There wont be any logs its straight forward integration btw sns and pagerDuty, For debugging you can also add your email address to sns topic along with pageduty email, so that you knows event is triggering and if pagerduty is not triggered then there might be some wrong configuration in pagerduty.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the **Amazon S3 Event**, you can specify a **Prefix**. This is effectively the same as a folder name:

[image: S3 Event]

You can configure the event to send a message to an **Amazon SNS topic** (great for sending email notifications) or an **Amazon SQS queue**, or to trigger an **AWS Lambda function**.